# Why does sort k1,1 changes the output?

Tags: shell, hadoop, terminal

I am new in hadoop world and I am trying to learn writing a code with map reduce mindset.

So, I was following the michael-noll tutorial.

One of the challenges, I am facing (besides understanding a new framework) is the amount of terminal tricks this framework uses.

So
What does.

```
  $echo "foo foo quux labs foo bar quux" | /home/hduser/mapper.py | sort -k1,1 | /home/hduser/reducer.py
```

means??? what does echo does??

Also, the output of above code is:

```
  bar     1
  foo     3
  labs    1
   quux    2
```

Now if i dont have the sort -k1,1 thingy

```
  foo     2
  bar     1
  labs    1
  foo     1
   quux    2
```

What is the effect that sort flag is having?
what does -k1,1 means?

Thanks..

Reference:  http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Linux, the vertical bar, `|` is used to redirect output of one command to be the input of another.

The `echo` command writes the following string to the standard output. So in your case, it is writing `foo foo quux labs foo bar quux` which is then passed as the input to `/home/hduser/mapper.py`, whose output is then passed as input to `sort`, and so on.

`sort` is a Linux command that sorts text. The `-k` flag tells it which column to sort by. So the `1,1` tells it to sort starting at column 1, ending at column 1.

Type `man sort` in your Linux terminal to learn more about the command. I hope this helps!

Comment: Also, you won't need to sort your data between the mapper and reducer when running a Hadoop Streaming job, the Hadoop MR framework will handle the sorting for you.

Comment: @HypnoticSheep: Hi What will be the "minimum" set of commands that will give me the same output as if i dont put the sort flag then the output is different ?? am i missing something? thanks

Comment: @Fraz I'm going to add the info to my answer below as I don't have enough space here.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be working in Hadoop Streaming, it may be helpful to run through [this tutorial](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/) first and learn to use shell commands. It'll help you out quite a bit down the line.

Basically, your output is different because of the way the Reducer works. It sums all values while the current key is the same as the last key. When the current key is different from the previous key, it writes out the value of the previous key and starts processing the current key. When your input looks like `foo foo bar foo`, the Mapper processes these values in order, producing an output like

```
foo 1
foo 1
bar 1
foo 1
```

This is then sent to your Reducer in the same format. Your Reducer reads it line by line. To give you a better understanding of this, here are the steps your Reducer takes:

```
// current_key = NULL
input_key,input_value: foo,1
input_key != current_key:
  current_key = input_key
  current_value = input_value
// current_value = 1

// current_key = foo
input_key,input_value: foo,1
input_key == current_key:
  current_value += input_value
// current_value = 2

// current_key = foo
input_key,input_value: bar,1
input_key != current_key:
  emit <current_key, current_value>
  current_key = input_key
  current_value = input_value
// current_value = 1

// current_key = bar
input_key,input_value: foo,1
input_key != current_key:
  emit <current_key, current_value>
  current_key = input_key
  current_value = input_value
// current_value = 1
```

This will give you the output of foo 2, bar 1, foo 1. Now, if you sort the input to the Reducer, it looks like this:

```
foo 1
foo 1
foo 1
bar 1
```

This makes it so that the Reducer continues to add the values of `foo` together without being interrupted by a `bar` key, so you get the output of foo 3, bar 1. Sorting the values can be done by `sort -k1,1`, which is a UNIX command that sorts based on the first field. The Hadoop MapReduce framework sorts intermediate values (ie. the foo 1, foo 1, bar 1, foo 1 data) automatically, so that all key,value pairs with the same key wind up at the same Reducer, producing the same output as if you had passed the intermediate values through `sort -k1,1`.